# Fill array inside each loop jquery

Tags: jquery, each

I would like to get values from the array created inside the each loop

```
var arr = [];

$.each([52, 97], function(index, value) {

    var arr = [value];

});

console.log(arr);
```

But the logged array has no entry.

Comment: Try use .pus() method to add elemnts to your array

Answer (score 2):

The error what you did is `var arr = [ value];` reinitialized variable, test this:

```
var arr =[];
$.each([ 52, 97 ], function( index, value ) {
 arr.push(value);
});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error what you did is `var arr = [ value];` reinitialized variable & wrong setting of array index.

```js
var arr = [];

$.each([52, 97], function(index, value) {

  arr[index] = value;

});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can also do this with `push()` as in other answer(@Boris Bresciani).

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `arr` inside the function is not the same as the outside variable `arr`, but local to the function. To fix that, do not create a new local variable, but let the function refer to the outside variable instead (this is called a closure). This should work:

```
var arr =[];
$.each([ 52, 97 ], function( index, value ) { 
  arr.push(value); 
});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **spread syntax** to get the array element copied without reference. This means that you can independently change the content of any array without affecting the content of other.

```js
var arr1 = [ 52, 97 ];
var res = [...arr1];
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add value in Array using each loop in js**

```js
var ProductTypeId = [];
$("input[name=ProductTypeId]").each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
        ProductTypeId.push($(this).val());
    }
});
alert(ProductTypeId`enter code here`);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="ProductTypeId" id="<?php echo $term['productTypeId']; ?>"  value="<?php echo $term['productTypeId']; ?>">
```